# Pandas - Convert excel Dataframe to specific dictionary format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I am trying to convert an excel file into a dictionary. I understand I can just turn it into a DataFrame and run ".to_dict()" with pandas. However I need it in a specific format . This is how the excel file is formatted below

---

```
trade   curve   1m    2m     3m    4m

90210   mega    555   222    111   9991

606066  sdsdsd  4545  63232  3232  62626926
```

---

I need the dictionary to look something like this.

```
{ trade : curve : [1m,2m,3m,4m ] }
```

Essentially, i want to have each trade have a value of a curve ( there might be the same trade, but different curve), and that curve to have an array as its value. I understand I need to look through the initial "to_dict", however im not sure how

Comment: do you want the dict should look like `{trade: {curve: [1m,2m,3m,4m]}}` where all these are column values ? your question isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dictionary by iterating the dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe=pd.read_excel("data.xlsx",header=None)
dictionary={}
for index,row in dataframe.iterrows():
    dictionary[row[0]]={row[1]:[]}
    dictionary[row[0]][row[1]].append(row[2])
    dictionary[row[0]][row[1]].append(row[3])
    dictionary[row[0]][row[1]].append(row[4])
    dictionary[row[0]][row[1]].append(row[5])

print (dictionary)
```

The above code will provide the below output:

```
{'trade': {'curve': ['1m', ' 2m', '3m', ' 4m']}, 90210: {'mega': [555, 222, 111, 9991]}, 606066: {'sdsdsd': [4545, 63232, 3232, 62626926]}}
```

I hope this is what you need.